# Connecting java with constraint logic programming

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse-clp

i'm trying to connect java with constraint logic, i'm using netbeans for java and eclipse 6.1 for constraint logic, but when i'm trying to run the code there is an exception appears **`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing eclipse.directory property`**

i've used a tutorial that explain how to connect them,  which says that After compilation, to run the program, start the Java interpreter as you normally would but before the name of the class, supply the command line option
 **`-Declipse.directory=<eclipse_directory>`**

and i don't know where to place it in netbeans

here is the code

```
import com.parctechnologies.eclipse.*;
import java.io.*;
public class eclipseConnection {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
      try{

    EclipseEngineOptions eclipseEngineOptions = new EclipseEngineOptions();
    EclipseEngine eclipse;
    eclipseEngineOptions.setUseQueues(false);
    eclipse = EmbeddedEclipse.getInstance(eclipseEngineOptions);
    eclipse.rpc("write(output, 'hello world'), flush(output)");
    ((EmbeddedEclipse) eclipse).destroy();
  }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should name your class `EclipseConnection`, in Java it's usual to start type names (i.e. classes, interfaces, enumerations) with capital case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the property definition in the 'Run' menu: `Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize...`. Make sure you enter the property definition `-Declipse.directory=<eclipse_directory>` in the `VM Options` section.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've set the directory, but there is another exception appears 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The shared library C:\Program\ECLiPSe\lib\i386_nt\ec_java_load.dll could not be found."
and the dll file already exists

Comment: "the dll file already exists" : were does the file exist? Ánd which is the `<eclipse_directory>` you configured?

Comment: the eclipse directory is C:\ Program Files\ECLiPSe and the dll file exist at the path C:\Program Files\ECLiPSe\lib\i386_nt\ec_java_load.dll

Comment: Ok, you probably need to escape the space character. Try putting the directory name in double quotes, e.g. `-Declipse.directory="C:\Program Files\ECLIPSe"` or `"-Declipse.directory=C:\Program Files\ECLIPSe"`. In worst case you will have to use the 8.3 name of the directory: `-Declipse.directory=C:\Progra~1\ECLIPSe`. PS Note for the future: never ever install your tools under or in a directory with spaces in it's name. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble, as you can see now.

Comment: @RanaMohamed I'm glad it worked. If you think my answer helped you and might help others, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the command line and the example source file Quicktest.java.

Copy the example:

```
copy "C:\Program Files\ECLiPSe 6.1\doc\examples\JavaInterface\Quicktest.java" .
```

Compile it:

```
javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\ECLiPSe 6.1\lib\eclipse.jar" QuickTest.java
```

Run it:

```
java -classpath ".;C:\Program Files\ECLiPSe 6.1\lib\eclipse.jar" -Declipse.directory="C:\Program Files\ECLiPSe 6.1" QuickTest
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help